# "Zero-downtime" Updates with S3 Static Site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

On a standard box, I'd typically have a set up as follows:

```
/timestamp-1/
/public/ (Symlink to /timestamp-1/)
```

I'd then upload the new site as `/timestamp-2/`, then once finished update the `/public/` symlink to point to `/timestamp-2/`.

Can something similar to this be achieved with S3 static sites?

Right now I've successfully got a domain hosted on Cloudflare pointing to a bucket with no issues.

I thought about renaming buckets to achieve this, but it turns out that's [not possible to do cleanly](http://www.witti.ws/blog/2014/09/26/rename-s3-bucket/).

The goal here is to reduce the amount of time it takes to swap out updates to the site.

Comment: Have you tried to set Nginx S3 proxy up, it gives you a full freedom on caching rules and facility to use **try_files** that helps to build zero downtime rotation

Comment: That requires that I add one more bit of infrastructure I'm trying to avoid for now.

Comment: You should be able to achieve what you want using RoutingRules although it would create a redirect: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html